# Galois theory and schemes (Mumford & Oda)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, schemes

I'm a little bit confused on a construction (2.2) in Definition 2.1 from Mumford's & Oda's [Algebraic Geometry II](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Algebraic%20Geometry%20II%20%28a%20penultimate%20draft%29) on pages 124-125

let $k$ a field and $\bar{k}$ the algebraic closure of $k$. let $Gal(\bar{k} / k)$ the Galois group. then every $\sigma_k \in Gal(\bar{k} / k)$ induces a map $\sigma_k: Spec \text{ } \bar{k} \to Spec \text{ } \bar{k}$ that is defined by $(\sigma_k)^*a= \sigma^{-1}a$ for $a \in \bar{k}$. let $\overline{X}:= X \times_k \bar{k}$.

> Definition 2.1 For a $k$-scheme X, define the conjugation action of $Gal(\bar{k} / k)$ on $\overline{X}$ to
>   be:

$$\sigma_X = 1_X \times \sigma_k : \overline{X} \to \overline{X}, \text{ all } \sigma_k \in Gal(\bar{k} / k)$$

> Then $\sigma_X$ fits into a diagram:

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\overline{X} @>{\sigma_X}>> \overline{X}\\
@VVV @VVV\\
Spec \text{ } \bar{k} @>{\sigma_k}>> Spec \text{ } \bar{k}
\end{CD}

> What this means is that if $f \in \mathcal{O}_{\overline{X}}(U)$ then $\sigma_X^*f \in \mathcal{O}_{\overline{X}}(\sigma_X ^{-1} U)$
>   has value at a point $x \in \sigma_X ^{-1} U$
>   given by:

\begin{equation}
(\sigma_X^*f)(x)=\sigma^{-1} \cdot f(\sigma_X \cdot x) \tag{2.2}\label{eq:0105star}
  \end{equation}

(???)

Q: I don't understand why the commutativity of diagram above imply that the equation for the sections (2.2) is true.

$\sigma_X$ induced maps $\sigma_X^*: \mathcal{O}_{\overline{X}}( U) \to \mathcal{O}_{\overline{X}}(\sigma_X ^{-1} U)$ and $(\sigma_X^*)_x: \mathcal{O}_{\overline{X}, \sigma_X \cdot x} \to \mathcal{O}_{\overline{X},x}$. evaluation of a section $f \in \mathcal{O}_{\overline{X}}( U)$ is nothing but composition $\mathcal{O}_{\overline{X}}( U) \to  \mathcal{O}_{\overline{X},x} \to \mathbb{k}(x)$ of canonical maps. why these observatons imply (2.2)? is the map $ \mathbb{k}(\sigma_X \cdot x) \to  \mathbb{k}(x) $ fully determined by $\sigma_k$ from the diagram?

Comment: Hint: combine the fact that the pullback of the zero function is the zero function and that the pullback of the constant functions is the constant functions twisted by $\sigma_k^{-1}$. The first fact is true because the pullback of sections is a ring homomorphism, and the second is true by looking at the bottom row of the diagram.

Comment: the hint leads me to looking for a expression of  $f \in \mathcal{O}_{\overline{X}}( U)$ as a sum $f=a+b$ with $a, b \in \mathcal{O}_{\overline{X}}( U)$ whereat $a \in \bar{k}$ or more precisely $a$ be a image under induced vertical map $\bar{k} \to \mathcal{O}_{\overline{X}}( U)$ and $b(x)=0$. a little diagram chaise shows that the pullback maps $a \in \bar{k}$ to $\sigma^{-1}a$ and image of $b$ non contribute to evaluation, because $\sigma_X^*$ is a *local* ring homomorphism. is this exactly the way, that was intened to be guided by your hint?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it.

Comment: the only part of your hint, which I haven't figured out yet is where do you make explicit use of the first fact that the pullback of zero function is zero? during my attept to apply your hint I nowhere used it

Comment: Your claim about the local homomorphism replaces that part of the hint. The way I was thinking of it was that you would replace $f$ by $f-a$ where $a$ was the value of $f$ at $x$. Then $f-a$ evaluates to $0$ at $x$, and we can continue with the rest of the argument. Your argument is perhaps a little more precise ($f-a$ isn't literally zero, it just evaluates that way), but I'm glad the idea helped you solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you again, Sir!